# Is there any way to improve the performance on Google Drive Sync?

Tags: google-drive

It seems to me that Google Drive Sync will never go above 15-20% of the system memory. Is there any way to lift this limit, or improve performance some other way? I guess I don't know for sure if I'm being throttled on Google's end or on my end, but I'm assuming that as a background service it is intended to take up only a limited footprint. During a large sync, is there any way to lift these limits until the sync is complete?

Answer (score -1):

The bottleneck is most likely your internet connection. The sync is mostly just a file transfer via internet that won't use much ram as it is just transferring files from your computer to the cloud or vice-versa. The only way to increase the speed would be to increase your internet connection speed. This process shouldn't take much ram or cpu usage.